# DynamoDB Document Client SDK v3 Add Item to Set

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When trying to add a value to a Dynamodb string set using the DynamoDB Document Client v3 I get the error:

```
Only Number Set (NS), Binary Set (BS), or String Set (SS) are allowed.
```

I see working examples for SDK v2 but not v3.

What's wrong with this simplified Typescript code?
Shouldn't the groups field (of type set) be marshaled correctly to a DynamoDB set?

```
import * as dynamodb from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import * as dynamodblib from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

const client = new dynamodb.DynamoDBClient({ region: this.props.region });
const ddbDocClient = dynamodblib.DynamoDBDocument.from(client);
const input = this.updateOneStatement(); // My code that creates input.
console.log(input);
const command = new dynamodblib.UpdateCommand(input);
const output = await ddbDocClient.send(command);

// console.log
{
  TableName: 'movie',
  Key: { id: '1' },
  UpdateExpression: 'ADD #groups :groups',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#groups': 'groups' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':groups': Set(1) { [Array] } },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE'
}

// Existing item to be updated:
{
  "id": {
    "S": "2"
  },
  "groups": {
    "SS": [
      "item1",
      "item2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required me to adapt your code a little to run on my local machine, but you'll understand how it works:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, UpdateCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "eu-west-1" });
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const groups = new Set(['item3', 'item4', 'item5']);

const input = {
    TableName: 'stack',
    Key: { id: '2' },
    UpdateExpression: 'ADD #groups :groups',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#groups': 'groups' },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':groups': groups },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE'
  }


const command = new UpdateCommand(input);
const output = docClient.send(command)
                        .then(res=>console.log(res))
                        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Very helpful to compare a working example. Rookie mistake. The issue boiled down to creating a set like this: new Set([[item3]]) instead of: new Set(['item3'])